# How do i define starting position of listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I want to define the listbox rows to start at 1, not the default 0. How do i do it ?

Comment: No, you don't.  Arrays and collections are zero-based for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are determined to do it, I would make a method

```
private int ListIndex(int index){
  return index - 1;
}
```

And then use ListIndex anywhere you index into the list, but as others pointed out, you really should shift your mindset to deal with 0 based indexes, as they are a standard in most programming situations.

Answer (score 3):

You dont. You basically learn to work within the context of the environment you use. WPF defines table positions in general to start at 0.

Feel free to program your own WPF replacement.

Comment: So you saying the c# isn't capable of defining starting position of listbox at 1 ?

Comment: Yes. it also would violate WPF AND (!) C# guidelines how controls should behave, so it would be something along the line of "talk about your attitude" in teams. It would make your code behavr different than other code without any gain.

Comment: @isa: Your statement makes no sense.  C# is capable of doing whatever you tell it to (it's a Turing-complete language).  You can (but **really** shouldn't) write your own ListBox that starts at `-42` if you want to.

Comment: How do i do that, that it starts with - 42 ? Can you post the code how i make it start with - 42 please ?

Comment: No, I won't.  It's an utterly horrible idea.

Comment: My computer won't explode lol, i just want to see how it is done.

Answer (score 1):

This is really an issue of why or why not you should begin indices (of any kind, for that matter) from 0. See [this post about the very topic](http://developeronline.blogspot.com/2008/04/why-array-index-should-start-from-0.html). There are, arguably, some good reasons for starting an index from 0.

There are also some legacy technical reasons. For example, in C, the array was actually a pointer to the first element of the array, and the form `array[i]` is equal to `*(array + i)`, meaning that what the index really refers to is the **offset** from the first element of the array. Thus, a 0 offset references the first element, and 1 offset references the second element, and so on.

It's all about mathematical beauty.

Comment: Yes, reading this article explains it simple, but it doesn't mentions c#

Comment: @isa Like I said, this has nothing to do with C# specifically. It applies to any language. The designers of C#, as well as a majority of other popular programming languages, decided that there were **good reasons** to start indices from 0. If you strongly disagree with that idea, then you can either switch to a language that does it differently, or make your own implementation. Trying to mess with C# to change the fundamental language design, however, is a pointless waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, you `can't` do that buddy.